Expectation of Bernoulli random variables and independence
Suppose $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be a sequence of Bernoulli random variables satisfying $$\mathbb E[X_{i_1}X_{i_2}\dots X_{i_k}]=\mathbb E[X_{i_1}]\mathbb E[X_{i_2}]\dots \mathbb E[X_{i_k}]$$ for any $2\leqslant k\leqslant n$ and $1\leqslant i_1\leqslant \dots <i_k\leqslant n$. Prove that $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are independent.
What I could show was $\mathbb P(X_{i_1}=1,\dots,X_{i_k}=1)=\mathbb P(X_{i_1}=1)\dots\mathbb P(X_{i_k}=1)$.
If one of $X_i$ is $0$ it comes $0$ as value of product. However I could not make further progress for what happens for $0$ s.

You can try induction aswell. Note that the product of Bernoulli is Bernoulli one.

I observe that if $X_i$ is Bernoulli then $1-X_i$ is also Bernoulli. Alternatively, I observe that $A_1, ..., A_n$ are mutually independent events, where $A_i={X_i=1}$.
